# Correct Way To Request Parameters In Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to request parameters in a PowerShell script without using a function.  With the following sample script I get an error if I don't include the Param within the function.

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

function SomeFunctionName
{

Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$CollectionUrl,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$SourceList,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$DestList,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$ExpireDays
) # END PARAMS


#DO SOMETHING WITH THE PARAMETERS
```

}

If I remove the "function" and surrounding brackets just try to request parameters directly in the script I get the following error:

> Missing closing ')' in expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the param(...) block at the top of the script before the If/Add-PSSnapin.  You can have comments before the param but no other script.